# Is it possible to disable a SystemVerilog task within a single specific class instance?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In SystemVerilog, one can use the `disable` construct to terminate named blocks or tasks. But I found today that disabling a task within a class instance affects all copies of the task in all class instances.

Consider a class which has a few tasks defined within it. If, internal to the class, there is a call to `disable <taskname>`, this will disable **all** copies of the task across all instances of the class.  This is not the behavior I expected, but it is correct according to the LRM:

> If a task is enabled more than once, then disabling such a task shall disable all activations of the task.

**Is there a mechanism or workaround to disable *only* the task within a specific instance of a class?**

The code below highlights the problem I am facing. Basically, I have a timer task which I want to disable due to some other event.  This is all contained within a class. In my verification environment I have multiple instances of this class and they operate entirely independently.  So disabling the timer within one instance should not affect the others.  But the way `disable` works it is affecting the other instances.

I tried `disable this.timer` but that did not compile.

In this example, I have two instances of `class c` which contains a `timer` task.  There is a `disabler` task which is started in parallel which makes the call to `disable timer`.  The intent in this example is for `timer` to get disabled half-way through its count. So `c1` would get disabled at time 5, and `c2` would get disabled at time 10.  However, they both are disabled at time 5, because the `disable timer` call originating in `c1` disables the task in both `c1` and `c2`.

```
module top();

  class c;

    string name;
    int    count;

    function new(string _name, int _count);
      name  = _name;
      count = _count;
    endfunction

    task t1();
      timer();
      $display("%t %s timer completed", $time, name);
    endtask

    task run();
      fork
        t1();
        disabler();
      join
    endtask

    task timer();
      $display("%t %s starting timer with count=%0d", $time, name, count);
      repeat(count) #1;
    endtask

    task disabler();
      repeat(count/2) #1;
      disable timer;
    endtask

  endclass

  class ex;

    c c1;
    c c2;

    function new();
      c1 = new("c1", 10);
      c2 = new("c2", 20);
    endfunction

    task run();
      fork
        c1.run();
        c2.run();
      join_none
    endtask

  endclass

  ex e = new;

  initial begin
    e.run();
  end

endmodule
```

Output:

```
               0 c1 starting timer with count=10
               0 c2 starting timer with count=20
               5 c2 timer completed
               5 c1 timer completed
```

I know I could rewrite this to get it to work without using `disable`, but it's such an easy way to terminate a task early that I'm hoping there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. Even using *disable* on named blocks will still stop all instances of that task.

> Disabling an automatic task or a block inside an automatic task
>   proceeds as for regular tasks for all concurrent executions of the
>   task.

You could try to use a process class. I've never used them myself so this code likely contains errors.

```
class c;
process p1;

task run();
  fork
    begin
      p1 = process::self(); //Get process of this begin..end block
      $display("%t %s starting timer with count=%0d", $time, name, count);
      repeat(count) #1;
    end
    disabler()
  join_none
endtask

task disabler();
  wait (p1 != null);
  repeat(count/2) #1;
  p1.kill();
endtask
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried using the process class already but could not get it to work. I revisited that and was able to make it work; the key is that the task/procedures that should be killed need to be in their own fork/join so they are in a separate process. So - it is possible, but not using `disable`.  But I'm not sure it's worth the effort and complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
class a1; 
  process p1; 

  task timer();
    p1=process::self();
    begin
      while(1)
      begin
        $display("example data %t",$time);
        #10;
      end 
    end 
  endtask

  task timer2();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) 
    begin
      #20;
      $display("shouldnot killed",i);
    end
  endtask

endclass

module example_kill;
  a1 ab,bc;
  initial begin 
    ab = new();
    bc= new();
    fork 
    ab.timer();
    ab.timer2();
    bc.timer();
    join_none
    #50; 
    ab.p1.kill();
    #100;
    bc.p1.kill();
    wait fork;
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tasks can be isolated inside threads. The idea is that you isolate your task inside a thread. You should apply the disable fork only for one specific instance. So you must ask about the instance where we are.
ere we have a problem because systemverilog doesn't allow you to 
 e.g.

`fork
  begin
    yourtaskcall;
  end 
join_none
if (class_instance_disable_member_id==1) begin
  disable fork;
end`

Afterwards you can wrap again the previous code so that you isolate the disable fork only for that task. e.g.

`fork
    begin 
    fork
      begin 
        yourtaskcall;
       end
    join_none
    if (class_instance_disable_member_id==1) begin
       disable fork;
    end
    end
join`

Lastly, from your top you should set the variable "**class_instance_disable_member_id**" to 1 (**default value=0**) for the specific instance you want to disable. This can be done from the outerclass or top class.

**e.g. top.class1.class_instance_disable_member_id=1;**

The task will be disable by the time the task is called. So you must set the "class_instance_disable_member_id=1 variable" before the call happens.
If you use UVM you can use phases (build or connect before run phase). If it is simple systemverilog then you can use the new() constructor to set that variable for the correct instance from the top.

If you want to activate/deactivate a task "on the fly/dynamically" then you should have another thread/task on the top that modifies that "class_instance_disable_member_id" for your specific instance before the task you want to disable is called.

You can also detect changes on the class_instance_disable_member_id to allow killing task in the middle, with the following basic block

`fork
  begin
    yourtaskcall;
  end 
  begin
    if (class_instance_disable_member_id==0) begin
       @(posedge class_instance_disable_member_id);
    end
  end 
join_any
if (class_instance_disable_member_id==1) begin
  disable fork;
end`

I hope it helps
BR